# CURL http_code ErrorDocument 404 redirect

Tags: curl, redirect, httprequest

I use the CURL command to get the http code of a web page:

```
curl -k -s -I -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" --proxy xxx.xxx.xxx:8080 https://www.yyy.com/myAPP
```

When myAPP is up and running, the code is 200.

Mt company enforces a redirect: if the http code is not **200**, e.g. **400** or **500**, a redirection to 
`https://www.yyy.com/server_responses/anyapp_outage_apology.htm`

The CURL command returns **302** not 400 or 500.

**How can I catch the real http code not the redirection's code?**

Comment: follow the redirect by adding `-L` perhaps?

Comment: @ Daniel Stenberg not sure where I can add the `-L`? on the command line? I tried, not help.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out how to get around this.

If the url used is:

```
https://www.yyy.com/myAPP
```

The request will be redirected to the specified page explaining the page is not, e.g. under construction, and the code is `302`.

If I **tail the url with the default file name**, e.g

```
https://www.yyy.com/myAPP/index.jsp
```

No redirect will take place, and the real http code, `404, 500`, etc will return.